# I cant figure out why my tinyMCE editor doesnt display text from the database

Tags: php, model-view-controller, tinymce, editor

I've been working on a CRUD project, within which i'm asked to use a tinyMCE editor for both publishing posts and editing them.
I got the publishing part to work correctly, but i' having trouble with the editing one.

The situation is as follow : using an MVC model, the view that generates the editing form is as such :

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php include("components/head.php") ?>

<body>
    <?php include("components/header.php") ?>
    <div class="containers">
        <div class="admincolumn1">

            <?php include("components/adminmenu.php") ?>

        </div>
        <div class="column2">
            <div class="Redaction">


                <form class="NewArticle" id="newArticle" method="POST" action="index.php?action=store-post">

                    <h2>Editez votre article</h2>
                    <div class="Articlecontainer">
                        <label for="Title"><strong>Titre:</strong></label>

                        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="Title" value=<?php $articleTitle ?>>
                        <label for="Subject"><strong>Votre Article:</strong></label>
                        <tinymce-editor api-key="0ki8kh44dpr0iupw97fjo8e0x3vrccw5i082axf6oco1elwv" name="Subject" value=<?php echo $articleText ?>>
                            <!--  <textarea name="Subject" rows=25 cols=150 value=<?php echo $articleText ?>></textarea> -->
                        </tinymce-editor>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit">Publier</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'tinymce-editor',
            setup: function(editor) {
                editor.setContent('<?php echo $articleText; ?>');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>`
```

As you can see there's a commented textarea, that existed before i used the tinyMCE editor. While the editor works, when i'm editing a post i fetch it through the controller with this function:

```
`function edit_post()
{
    // grab post ID
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;
    if ($id == 0) {
        header("Location: http://projet4git/index.php?action=admin");
    }

    // match post and ID
    $Post = new posts_model();
    $singlePost = $Post->getOnePostById($id);


    require("./views/edit_post.php");
}`
```

and this function calls the model to fetch the post by its ID :

```
`public function getOnePostById($id)
    {
        $query = $query = "SELECT id, titre, message, date FROM posts WHERE id= :id";
        $request = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $request->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $request->execute();
        $singlePost = $request->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



        return $singlePost ? $singlePost : [];
    }`
```

this all results in the post returning its text directly when the edit_post() function is called, at least when using the textarea instead of the tinyMCE editor, when using the tinyMCE editor the editor itself remains empty instead of displaying the text that it should display, and i'm struggling to figure out why.
PS: my head component does feature the script src for tinyMCE :

```
`<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/main.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/50ab74dd38.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/0ki8kh44dpr0iupw97fjo8e0x3vrccw5i082axf6oco1elwv/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tinymce/tinymce-webcomponent@1/dist/tinymce-webcomponent.min.js"></script>;
    <title>Document</title>
</head>`
```

As i said above, what i expected was to get the text to automatically be inserted within the tinyMCE editor, after some research i found out about `getContent()` and `setContent()` from the tinyMCE documentation but those did not work properly, in my best attempt, it would simply send me back an error message saying that $articleText wasnt defined, which i find strange since echo'ing it works fine with the textarea method.
It must be noted that $articleText is a variable that exists when initially publishing a post withing the model,where its defined as the data from the named field "Subject" :

```
`  public function post($data)
    {
        $articleTitle = htmlspecialchars($data['Title']);
        $articleDate = date('Y-m-d');
        $articleText = htmlspecialchars($data['Subject'], ENT_QUOTES);

        if (!empty($articleTitle) && !empty($articleText)) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO posts(titre,message,date) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            $request = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $request->execute([$articleTitle, $articleText, $articleDate]);
        }
        //check insertion
        if ($request->rowCount() == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }`
```

Comment: I'm kind of curious if you've got any console errors, looking at `editor.setContent('<?php echo $articleText; ?>');` without knowing the content of your article text, this is going to need the quotes escaped, eg you could also try `editor.setContent(<?php echo json_encode($articleText); ?>);`

Comment: the $articleText variable contains whatever the DB has under "message", which is text with formatting (from tinyMCE), nothing else. As for errors the only one returned by the console was : DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: My TinyMCE implementation is kind of complicated, it's a .NET WPF using Chromium. But what I found is carriage returns and/or newlines in the html will cause setContent to completely fail.